# How to clear a frame and reuse it in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create normal program where I can access to my daily things from one application but as I created it with Tkinter. I want to take input like for example, username and password, then just clear the screen and show pictures on small buttons.

code-

```
from tkinter import font
from PIL import *
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time
import os
import webbrowser

window=Tk()
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.configure(bg="Black")

t=Label(window,text="Hello User",fg="blue",bg="red")
font=("Arial", 55) 
t.place(x=650 ,y=20)
p=Entry(window,width=25,show="*")
p.place(x=600,y=500)

def clears(widget):
window_grid.forget()



def yett(event):
global oof

oof=(p.get())

if oof=='1234' :
    l=Label(window,text="hello")
    l.place(x=190, y=230)
    
    newbun=Button(window,text="New window",command=clears)
    newbun.place(x=400 , y=20)
    p['state']=DISABLED
else:
    p.destroy()

window.bind('<Return>', yett)
    


window.mainloop()
```

error-

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter              \__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: clears() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget'
```

Comment: Please provide a [rme] showing the inability to use the frame afterwards.

Comment: Dont destroy it, instead `frame.<geometry_manager>_forget()` it

Comment: @martineau I cant add anything in the window afterwards.

Comment: @CoolCloud ill check if that works

Comment: stackoverflower: I know, you said that in the question. I want you to add code to the question that proves it, a [mre].

Comment: @CoolCloud: The OP isn't destroying the frame, just its children.

Comment: @CoolCloud now its giving me different error - "clears() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget'"

Comment: @stackoverflower Post the entire error code in the question please

Comment: @CoolCloud here-

Comment: @stackoverflower There are more errors in the code tho

Comment: @CoolCloud 
I know its not finished yet as I cant pass through the first one.

Comment: No, I mean syntax errors